# flexipage:availableForAllPageType Interface in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

I am trying to configure my Lightning component to show up on the Lightning app builder, and tried to implement the interface as listed in docs,

```
<aura:component controller="stech.CalendarController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
```

But I am getting an error
Failed to save undefined: No INTERFACE named markup://flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes found : [markup://stech:calendar]: Source

I tried adding namespaces but I get a different error then
Failed to save undefined: Invalid Descriptor Format: flexipage:stech.availableForAllPageTypes[INTERFACE]: Source

Does anyone know how to use this interface? Also related question, how do I add design resource to the bundle?

PS:I have the Lightning App Builder enabled in the org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your org running on Spring '15? This is required - Winter did not have this capability exposed.

Comment: hmm not yet, i will be upgraded next week to spring 15. I have a demo spring 15 org,but i dont have lightning app builder in that org, but let me try it and see if it works there. Thank you

Comment: yep it works on Spring 15. I guess I need to wait another week to get it onto my org.. Thank you Doug.